# Jquery populate select menu list not working in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, select, internet-explorer-9

I am populating a select form menu list based on another menu selection (in wordpress) with jquery code below. It works fine in all browsers excepet ie9/8. Any advice appreciated.

```
$jmake = $j("select[name='make']");
$jmodel = $j("select[name='model']");

$jmake.change(function (){
if($j(this).val() == "ALFA ROMEO") {
    $j("select[name='model'] option").remove();
    $j("<option>GT</option>").appendTo($jmodel);
    $j("<option>BRERA</option>").appendTo($jmodel);
    }
```

..hopefully that's clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is syntax error in your script:

```
$jmake.change(function (){
if($j(this).val() == "ALFA ROMEO") {
    $j("select[name='model'] option").remove();
    $j("<option>GT</option>").appendTo($jmodel);
    $j("<option>BRERA</option>").appendTo($jmodel);
    }
);
```

Comment: if you mean the last line sorry that is in - and it works fine in ff etc

Answer (score 0):

try below.

```
$jmodel.append('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
```

Comment: Thanks - where do I put this/what to overwrite?

Comment: change your 2 lines that setting <option> with the above line. that would result as  $jmodel.append('<option></option>').val("GT").html("GT") and $jmodel.append('<option></option>').val("BRERA").html("BRERA")

Comment: sorry no effect in ie, still not showing anything on 2nd select list